# Integer - String conversion issue in Java

Tags: java

What is the best way to convert String to Integer.

`params.get("contractPriceId");` here I am getting Exception cannot cast Integer to String...

```
public List<ContractPriceDetailVO> getContractPriceDetails(
        Map<String, String> params) throws DAOException {
    // Get the request object
    HttpServletRequest request = FlexContext.getHttpRequest();
    // Get the AppContext object
    AppContext ac = SessionUtils.getAppContext(request);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ac.getDateFormat());
    List<Object[]> resultList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    if (params.get("specId") != null && params.get("specId").trim() != ""
            && params.get("effDate") != null
            && params.get("effDate").trim() != null)
        resultList = contractPriceEJBService.getContractPriceDetails(ac,
                params);

    String contractPriceId = null;
    if (params.get("contractPriceId") != null){
        try{
        contractPriceId = params.get("contractPriceId");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Exception in getting contractPriceId "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else{
        contractPriceId = null;
    }
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt ("123");

Comment: This question is currently _very_ unclear. It is unclear what your exception is and where you try to convert something, because you're only working with `String`. Please [edit] your question to add missing information. Also read: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Which exception are you getting ?

Normally we use,

```
int price = Integer.parseInt("7");
```

This returns the int value of string.

Please put the exception and error in the question so we can do more analysis of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this and it should work

```
contractPriceId = params.get("contractPriceId") +"";
```

Comment: So you think it is clever to append an empty String to a String? For what?

Comment: @Tom It's clever since `params.get("contractPriceId")` returns an Integer.

Comment: So you think the map `params` (`Map<String, String> params`) returns integer, although it is declared to return String? Really?

Comment: @Tom Didn't see that one, I went with the declaration `String contractPriceId = null;`. Which in this case shouldn't be a problem. Unless he copy pasted smth wrong

Comment: Well, this question is really unclear, because we don't know where he tries to cast something and what his issue/exception is. One can try to help/answer, but this can result in wrong posts, because the question is so unclear (or maybe wrong). So the best way to handle this is to flag as "unclear" and to leave a comment under the question :).

Comment: Btw: let's pretend `params.get("contractPriceId")` returns an `int` (or `Integer`): don't just append an empty String to it. The better/cleaner way would be `String.valueOf(params.get("contractPriceId"))`.

Comment: @Tom Yup it's better from the perspective of efficiency.

Comment: You'd rather explain why your answer would solve his problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Integer to String, String.valueOf(47).

From String to Integer, Integer.parseInt("47").

To avoid the exception, try String.valueOf(params.get("contractPriceId")).

Comment: This `String.valueOf(params.get("contractPriceId"))` is not needed, because `params.get("contractPriceId")` already returns a `String` (look at the declared type for the `params` parameter).

Comment: if the parameter "contactPriceId" is not present in the Map, it would return null. Even if the declared type is String, I don't think that a null value can be assumed as any type.

Comment: The result of your suggestion would be the String `"null"` and it is currently not known that OP wants that. Well the whole question is unclear anyway.

Comment: You are right, but this is not suppose to happen, because he is validating the parameter not to be null. I do not really figure out how this exception is thrown in this line, so I thought he could avoid it by converting anything that receives to a String.